# Starcraft 2 to add more units to a group using on-screen "Control Groups" buttons?

Tags: starcraft-2, control-group

I want to add more units to my current group, e.g. at hotkey `1`, using the on-screen `ControlGroups` buttons.

Currently we achieve this by `Shift-1` via hotkey. I want to do this on-screen i.e. holding `Shift` and right clicking on `button 1` on the screen.

How can I do that?

Comment: AutoHotkey maybe?

Comment: @ardaozkal I'm looking for on-screen solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: why would you want to do that? use the keyboard it's way faster, you should even change the control groups to "unclickable" or "hidden" so you don't accidently click it during game.

Comment: @Aequitas That may be necessary for unfortunate people with less than usual number of fingers, or who are otherwise unable to use their off-hand in an intended way.

Comment: @NamGVU, you probably mean Shift-1? Ctrl-1 overwrites the group, not adds to it.

Comment: @OrcJMR Yeah, you're right about `Shift-1`. I've updated

Comment: @OrcJMR Yeh but you're just guessing as to what the reason is and since the answer is "you can't" we need to know the reason why he wants to do it in order for an appropriate work around to be suggested. Like in your answer you provide a work around but what if the reason that they want to use the on screen control groups is because they don't have a shift key? or a keyboard even? That would invalidate your answer.

Comment: @Adequitas My reason is that I want to use `0` or `7,8,9` key to mark `research building` and I'm very slow with `shift-0` or `shift-9`. I can quickly `shift select` the building on-screen and wish to set the group by `keeping shift` and `right click` on the number(s)

Comment: To me, adding to `control group` by `shift-right click` is just faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage your control groups using the mouse - to some extent. To do that, Control Groups seting in Options -> Gameplay should be set to "Normal".

- **Left click** on a control group tab selects units from the group (what is done by pressing a number key on the keyboard).
- **Right click** on a control group tab assigns currently selected units to the group (what is done by pressing Ctrl-number on the keyboard).

Those commands appear to be all one can do with the mouse, neither left nor right click are modified by Shift, Alt or Ctrl keys.

Considering the above, the actions to add units to an existing control group would be:

1. recall the control group by left-clicking its tab,
2. Shift-select newly drafted units,
3. assign the control group by right-clicking its tab.

Simply adding units when you already have only new ones selected is impossible.

Comment: Great thanks! Should recall curent group and `shift-left click` is the work around for now.